# first-order linear differential equation with boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvector

let be the differential equation

$ -ixDf(x)-if(x)/2= E_{n}f(x) $

with the boundary conditions $ f(x)=f(p^{k}x) $ for 'p' prime and $k=...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...$

is this possible to solve this eigenvalue problem ?? thanks

Comment: here D is the derivative operator with respect to 'x' and the boundary conditions apply to ALL the primes $ p=2,3,5,7,.... $

Comment: Your "boundary condition" does not appear to be a boundary condition in the usual sense.  Is this supposed to be for all $x$?  If $f(x) = f(p^kx)$ for all $x$ and all primes $p$ and integers $k$, then $f(x) = f(rx)$ for all positive rationals $r$, and then if $f$ is continuous it is constant.

Comment: As for the differential equation, its general solution is $f(x) = c x^{iE_n - 1/2}$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: wouldn't the function $ F(x)= \sum_{q}f(qx) $ with a sum taken over all the positive rational would satisfy the boundary conditions ?? with $ F(0)=0 $ and $ \int_{0}^{\infty} F(x)dx =0 $

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, such a sum won't converge unless $f=0$ everywhere.

Comment: aja.. however if we assume that $ f$ is a DISTRIBUTION instead of a funciton is there a possibility to get a different result to $ f=0 $ ?? thanks for your answers

Comment: Actually no: if $f$ is a distribution and $g$ is a test function, 
$\int f(rx) g(x)\ dx = r^{-1} \int f(t) g(t/r) dt$ is a continuous function of $r \ne 0$, so  the sum can't converge in the sense of distributions unless all the terms are $0$.

Comment: umm then perhaps my condition is too restrictive , how about only invariance under $ f(x)= fp^{k}x) $ here 'p' means all the primes $ p =2 ,3,5,7,..... $ and k=1,2,3,4,5,.. $ is still $ f=0$ ?? thanks :)

Comment: $f(x) = f(p^k x)$ means $f(p^{-k} t) = f(t)$ where $t = p^k x$, so you haven't changed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question, you first fix $p$, and then you search the solutions of $$−ixDf(x)−if(x)/2=E_nf(x)$$
which satisfy $f(px)=f(x)$ (by reccurence, your $p^k$ conditions is automatically satisfied).
So we solve the differential equation and we find $cx^{iE_n-1/2}$ and your condition gives $p^{iE_n-1/2}=1$. This is satisfied if and only if it exists some integer $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $(iE_n-1/2)\ln p=2in\pi$. So the possible values of $E_n$ and then eigenfunctions are
$$E_n=\frac{2in\pi}{\ln p}-i/2\qquad f_n(x)=ce^{\frac{2in\pi\ln x}{\ln p}}$$
If you intend not to fix first the value of $p$, then we need to consider only the solutions valid for all prime $p$. Then only solution is then for $n=0\;$ which gives
$$E=-i/2\qquad f(x)=c$$